# com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.component can not be resolved

Tags: java, aem

I am having trouble solving this one as I am completely new to AEM.
I have installed AEM 6.4.0

When I built the my code base, the core bundle does not gets Activated and stays in Installed state.
On finding the cause I saw that below mentioned packages were not getting resolved.

Imported Packages   com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.components,version=[1.0,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.components.details,version=[1.1,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.components.predicates,version=[2.2,3) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.configuration,version=[1.2,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.content,version=[1.0,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.content.properties,version=[1.1,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.search.searchpredicates,version=[1.0,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.aem.commons.assetshare.util,version=[1.4,2) -- Cannot be resolved

I checked the http://localhost:4502/system/console/depfinder and could not find any of these dependencies there. which means none of the already installed active bundles are is/are exporting these packages.

In my paren POM of project the dependency is included as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.adobe.aem.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>assetshare.core</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.adobe.aem.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>assetshare.ui.apps</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <type>content-package</type>
</dependency>
```

Inside the core POM it is included as dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.adobe.aem.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>assetshare.core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can somebody help me to any article or something you might have experience. Since I googled many things and could not understand anything as I am new to AEM.

Answer (score 1):

Asset Share commons is not an AEM out of the box package. It is an open source reference implementation built on AEM and is available via [this GitHub link](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/asset-share-commons).

You may need to build and install the asset share commons project as well to your AEM server as well using the steps mentioned in the same GitHub readme file.

This would resolve the dependencies of your project and would activate your bundle.

Alternatively, you can just download the `asset-share-commons.ui.apps-1.6.2.zip` and `asset-share-commons.ui.content-1.6.2.zip` packages from the following link and install it in your AEM server via package share.

https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/asset-share-commons/releases/tag/asset-share-commons-1.6.2

P.S: If you are building and installing the Github project, ensure you build and install the right version of the asset share package as mentioned in your dependencies or update your dependencies to point to the latest version.